# upload a file and display its content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, flask

In my react project, there is a screen where the user can upload a file (excel, csv) from their computer. After uploading, currently, nothing happens. However, I want to print or display whatever text is inside the uploaded on my screen (in any format for now). However, I am not sure how and where I need to store the file for now. How can I achieve this?

This is how I am uploading the file atm:

```
import Uploady from "@rpldy/uploady";
import UploadButton from "@rpldy/upload-button";


export function Page() {
    
  return (
    <div>
      <main>
      <Uploady
    destination={{ url: "https://my-server/upload" }}>
    <UploadButton/>
</Uploady>
        <div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload and read a file in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119987/upload-and-read-a-file-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the post function to uplode it in a API ,and then you have to fetch the data from the API and can store the response,you can use axios for this.

Comment: depending on what "uploady" is, you should be able to access the contents of the file even BEFORE uploading [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: This kind of suggestion without code you can add as comment on main question.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has already been answered, you can check it out -> [Upload and read a file in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119987/upload-and-read-a-file-in-react)